# New JavaScript files not included in the Rails Pipeline?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I have a rails 5 app to which I added two Javascript files to load  some d3 charts I built. For some reason, they are not getting recognized. When I run my local server and check out the source code, they are nowhere to be found. I get other Js files to come insert data/visualizations correctly because I have:

```
//= require_tree .
```

listed in my application.js and all should be working well. Do I need to run any specific commands to get the pipeline to recognize additional files?

Thanks! Let me know if there's any more info I can provide :)

Comment: Just a stab in the dark. Stop your server. In console, run 'spring stop'. Restart your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this issue in one of my projects and ended up using [iblue/d3-rails](https://github.com/iblue/d3-rails)

```
gem "d3-rails"
```

and add `//= require d3` to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. The library is actively maintained.